# Linux: Command to delete line(s) from XML file with matching string starting with the 2nd occurrence

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a XML file that looks something like this:

```
<Header version= '1.0' timestamp='2017-01-04T07:10:07'>
   <Date>2017-04-18</Date>
   .
   .
   .`
</Header>
<Header version= '1.0' timestamp='2017-01-04T07:10:07'>
   <Date>2017-04-18</Date>
   .
   .
   .`
</Header>
<Header version= '1.0' timestamp='2017-01-04T07:10:07'>
   <Date>2017-04-18</Date>
   .
   .
   .`
</Header>
```

I would like to delete the "Header" (and not /Header) lines starting with the 2nd occurrence - don't ask why :-). So the output should look something like this (yes, I know that it is not well formed, but I am going to perform other processing on it as well):

```
<Header version= '1.0' timestamp='2017-01-04T07:10:07'>
   <Date>2017-04-18</Date>
   .
   .
   .`
</Header>
<Date>2017-04-18</Date>
   .
   .
   .`
</Header>
<Date>2017-04-18</Date>
   .
   .
   .`
</Header>
```

I tried:

```
sed -i '2,${/<Header/d;}' file
```

but that deleted all the occurrences of Header. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Cyrus Could be a XY problem, true. But it is not so hard to do what OP wants, as to make understanding what the Y is important. However, OP, the recommendation by Cyrus (thinking of alternate ways to achieve the ultimate goal) is valid. You might spend some thought that way.

Comment: it makes no sense - after such deletion your xml will become invalid

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.) for your XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<\/Header/,${/^<Header/d}' file
```

From the first closing `Header` tag to the end of the file, remove any lines beginning with a `Header` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  "/<Header/{p;:a;s/^.*$//;N;s/\n//;/<Header/!p;ba}" input.txt
```

- find the first occurence
- print it
- start a loop

  - forget the current line
  - get the next
  - get rid of the unwanted newline
  - print it if it is not a match
- loop

This assumes that your header lines are always a single line. Otherwise it gets tough. In that case, think about whether this might be a XY problem (see comment by Cyrus).
I also assume that removing the indentation of the date lines is not actually wanted.

Comment: I tried the above, but am getting an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown command: `z'

Comment: I just used this command from another post and it worked:

    awk '!/^<Header/ || !f++' file

Comment: @user3152289 I avoided the `z`, which seems not to be supported by your sed. Maybe try my changed answer, just to test whether it works on your sed, too. Use whatever helps you. Consider making your own answer, having three different styles would be cool.